# Stochastic process $\exp(W_t - t/2)$ approaches zero for large $t$, but it is a martingale?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

The stochastic process
$$
 S_t = \exp\left( W_t - \frac{1}{2} t \right)
$$
is a martingale (for example this could be seen by noting that it solves the SDE $dS_t = S_t dB_t$, which has no drift).

But this does not make intuitively sense for me, if $t$ is large, then $W_t - \frac{1}{2} t$ looks like the straight line $-\frac{1}{2}t$ with little perturbations, so this expression is very likely a large negative number, and therefore the exponential of this should be near zero. If it would be a martingale, then it expectation for each point in future should be the starting value, which in this case is $S_0 = \exp(0) = 1$ almost surely, and not $0$.

I also made some pictures of this process, using $R$ and the following code

```
N=1000
d=rnorm(N)
W=cumsum(d)
c=W-0.5*(1:N)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(W,type="l")
plot(c,type="l")
plot(exp(W),type="l")
plot(exp(c),type="1")
```

Which gives the output (the process $S_t$ is the one on the bottom on the right, and above is the process $W_t - t/2$, which resembles the straight line for large $t$):

[image]

So I do not understand, if it should be a martingale then it should not approach zero for large $t$, instead it should stay around its starting value (for most samples of course, but this process will approach zero for most samples, so this is not just a random deviation)?

Comment: Your process is an example of a non-negative martingale that converges to zero. There is no contradiction. Here is a discrete example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352570/martingale-not-uniformly-integrable/352574#352574

Comment: Okay, this confuses me a bit at the moment, I thougth for large values the stochastic process converges to the expectation (according to the law of large numbers)... how could I expect a stochastic process to have the value $1$ if it almost surely approaches zero? Do you have any intuitive explanation for this?

Comment: Take a close look at the discrete example, where $\mathbb{E}(M_n)=1$ for all $n$ but $M_n\to 0$ almost surely. There is no contradiction.

Comment: For you discrete example I see that the overwhelming number of path's lead to zero, but the one that does not leads to zero, grows quite fast, i.e. it is $2^n$, so this large value in some way compensates all the zero paths in the computation of the expectation. But in my example I do not see some large paths that compensate, for me it always goes down...

Comment: Maybe for the rare cases that $W_t > t/2$ we have exponential grow, but this does not happen that much (maybe never), as $W_t \le \sqrt t$ almost always (we have $W_t \sim \mathcal N(0,t)$).... in your discrete example I can clearly see the one path that compensates for all...

Comment: Your example and mine are very similar: with probability one, **all** paths converge to zero.  Sorry, I don't think I can explain it better.

Comment: Another martingale $M$ with expectation $1$, which converges almost surely to $0$, is $M_t=W_{t\wedge \tau}$ where $W$ is a standard Brownian motion starting from $W_0=1$ and $\tau=\inf\{t\mid W_t=0\}$. Then $\tau$ is an almost surely finite stopping time hence $M$ is a martingale and $M_t\to0$ almost surely since $M_t=0$ for every $t\geqslant\tau$.

Comment: Sometimes in textbooks it is written that **"a martingale is a stochastic process that has no tendency to rise or fall"**, is this then just wrong and a misunderstanding? As in the examples here there is indeed some tendency of the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are confusing the mean and mode of your distribution, which is asymetric.

$S_t$ follows a lognormal distribution with parameters $\mu = -\frac{1}{2} t$ and $\sigma^2 = t$. So, $E [S_t] = e^{\mu + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2} = e^{-\frac{1}{2}t + \frac{1}{2} t} = e^0 = 1$, but the mode of the distribution is $e^{\mu - \sigma^2} = e^{-\frac{3}{2}t}$.

So, as $t \rightarrow \infty$, the mean remains $1$ (it is a martingale), but the mode goes to $0$. Intuitively, this is necessary to compensate unbounded values on the up side with bounded values on the down side.